# Oracle Apex- Update field in dml form on basis of another field which is not primary key

Tags: oracle-apex

Can we update a columns value based on another column name in dml form?

Ex: I have created a normal region with static content.
P1_PERSON_ID - Primary key
P1_PERSON_NAME
P1_ASSIGNED_DEPT
P1_APPROVER

In processing- Automatic DML Processing set.
So when this page is run, i wish to select person name (it is select list) and for that person and that assigned_Dept set approver value.

As i select person name, it would in backend fetch person id which is primary key and accordingly update other columns.

So say when i select Person_Name -> Mark, Assigned_Dept HR and put Approver as 1.
I want the table, it_people in this case to update approver as 1 for person_name as Mark and dept as HR.
Something like update it_people set approver-1 where person_name= Mark and assigned_Dept=HR.
Primary key is PERSON_ID but because the form wont have any prefetched value for particular employee, i want it to update one column based on another column values.
Is it possible?

P.S. I had raised similar question but could not explain the correct issue so raised here to clearly mention the requirement.

[Oracle Apex 20.1 Automatic DML processing not working to save updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816046/oracle-apex-20-1-automatic-dml-processing-not-working-to-save-updates)

Old thread

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to your data so I gave it a try with the sample dataset EMP/DEPT. This is a testcase that does exactly what you describe.

- Create a form with report on table emp
- In the form attributes, only check "Update Row" as "Allowed Operations"
- For this example, I want to select an employee and update his salary using built in row processing. So I hid all the columns except for the SAL column. Then I made the P1_EMPNO a select list (instead of hidden). This is the primary key field, so if you make it a select list, the selected value in the select list is the primary key for the row you want to update. Source query for P1_EMPNO:

```
SELECT ename,
       empno
  FROM emp
```

Now access the form via the "edit" link on the emp report for any employee. Select an employee and change the salary. If you save the correct row is updated.

--Koen